# Failure checkbox using MVC asp.net and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I using this code when the `checkbox True/False` is checked:

1. `A value` >>> not required and disable this field
2. `B value` >>> required

But I have problem because when the **checkbox True/False is unchecked** and clicking on btnConfirm... **the field B is required.**..

I need

1. when the checkbox is **unchecked the field B is not required**
2. when the checkbox is **checked the field B is required**

Can you help me?

My code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            EnableDisable($("[id*=Truefalse]"));
 
            $("[id*=Truefalse]").click(function () {
                EnableDisable($(this));
            });
 
            $("[id*=btnConfirm]").click(function () {
                if ($('#B').val() == '' && $('#B').attr('disabled') == undefined) {
                    alert('B value is required.');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
 
        function EnableDisable(element) {
            if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                $('#A').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#B').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#A').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="container">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group" style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; border:3px solid; font-weight:bold;">
                        <h5 style="font-weight: bold; text-indent: 20px;">
                            True/False @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Truefalse, true)
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.A)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.A, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Class = "Mytextarea2", placeholder = "A" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.B)
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.B, new { style = "width: 420px; height: 100px;", placeholder = "B" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="btnConfirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you change your `if` statement like this `if ($('#B').val().trim() == '' && $('#B').attr('disabled') == undefined &&   $("[id*=Truefalse]").is(":checked")) { //your codes }` see if that works .